# How mod rewrite can impact on PHP, JS or AS3 variables and paths

Tags: php, javascript, flash, .htaccess

Mod rewrite changes the look of URLs  but does it matter for server-side scripts (PHP)?
Does it change the $_GET[] in PHP? Will sth like:

`if ( strpos($pulledId,':') > 0 ) {
$pulledId = substr($pulledId,0,strpos($pulledId,':'));
}`

work, when there is no "id=" in diplayed URL? 
How about JavaScript? 
How about Flash? Can mod rewrite be a problem when loading external files from server ?

AS3 or JS are client-side scripts. So I assume they get URL as it is in a browser,
but PHP, JAVA are server-side, so they should get URL which haven't been processed by mod rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` can perform two types of redirections:

- Internal redirections: `RewriteRule ^catalogue/product-(\d+)/?$ products.php?product_id=$1 [L]`
- HTTP redirections: `RewriteRule ^foo?$ http://example.com/bar [L]`

Additionally, it can strip off the original query string or append it to the resulting URL (if you use the `[QSA]` flag).

PHP basically sees the same as the browser unless there's an internal redirection, in which case it sees the final URL and (optionally) the original query string.

Answer (score 1):

No, `$_GET` does not change on the server. That is the main point of mod_rewrite.

On the client side, yes, the URI will be different — they can only see what's in the address bar.

With Java, it depends on where you're executing it, so see above for that also.